# Can I display my JSON data in Table format using DataTable in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I'm successfully getting my JSON response in cosole. Trying to display it in table format using `DataTable` in flutter.
I tried to use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/json_table) but it only accepting JSON array list format.But my JSON is not in Array List.

My JSON response simply a `<Map>` What syntax I should use to display it in table?

```
{
"EncPartnerId": "LEuT1eIlpLEMAAkZme3wpQ==",
"EncTestId": "U4exk+vfMGrn7cjNUa/PBw==",
"Fee": "100",
"DiscountedFee": "80",
"BookingFee": "50"
}
```

My API function:

```
Future<void> GetTestFee() async {
var jsonResponse;
if (encTestId.isNotEmpty) {
  var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("http://medbo.digitalicon.in/api/medboapi/GetTestFee"),
      body: ({
        'EncPartnerId': "LEuT1eIlpLEMAAkZme3wpQ==",
        'EncTestId': "U4exk+vfMGrn7cjNUa/PBw==",

      }));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print("Correct");
    print(response.body);
    jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body.toString());
    print(jsonResponse);
    //Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DieticianAfterDateSelectPage( rresponse: DieticianEncBookingIdModel.fromJson(jsonResponse),)));
     ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Test Added")));
  } else {
    throw Exception("Faild to fetch");
  }
} else {
  throw Exception("Faild to fetch");
}

 }
```

Then insted of Dummy data how can I display my JSON response data? Should I use `ListView.builder?`

```
Container(
   child: Column(
    children:[
        DataTable(
              columns: <DataColumn>[
              DataColumn(label: Text("Test Name")),
              DataColumn(label: Text("Fee")),
              DataColumn(label: Text("Discounted Fee")),
              ],

              rows: <DataRow>[
                DataRow(
                   cells: <DataCell>[
                   DataCell(Text("jjj")),
                   DataCell(Text("jsjf")),
                   DataCell(Text("jsjf")),
               ]
             )
          ]
        )
     ]
  )

)
```

Comment: [flutter-map-in-data-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66067146/flutter-map-in-data-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map your json data to datatable like this

```
class User {
String? encPartnerId;
String? encTestId;
String? fee;
String? discountedFee;
String? bookingFee;

User(
  {this.encPartnerId,
  this.encTestId,
  this.fee,
  this.discountedFee,
  this.bookingFee});

User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  encPartnerId = json['EncPartnerId'];
  encTestId = json['EncTestId'];
  fee = json['Fee'];
  discountedFee = json['DiscountedFee'];
  bookingFee = json['BookingFee'];
}

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
  final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
  data['EncPartnerId'] = this.encPartnerId;
  data['EncTestId'] = this.encTestId;
  data['Fee'] = this.fee;
  data['DiscountedFee'] = this.discountedFee;
  data['BookingFee'] = this.bookingFee;
  return data;
 }
}

class DataTableEg extends StatefulWidget {
const DataTableEg({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_DataTableEgState createState() => _DataTableEgState();
}

class _DataTableEgState extends State<DataTableEg> {
 User? user;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getData();
 }

 void getData() {
 // final response=         //your api call
 // user=User.fromJson(response.body);
 }
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return DataTable(columns: <DataColumn>[
    DataColumn(label: Text("EncPartnerId")),
    DataColumn(label: Text("EncTestId")),
    ], rows: <DataRow>[
    DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[
    DataCell(Text(user?.encPartnerId ?? '')),
    DataCell(Text(user?.encTestId ?? '')),
    ])
  ]);
}
}
```

Comment: I believe My json response is not a Array list object.

Comment: create model based on your json and then you can use it in data table

Comment: [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60498520/how-can-we-use-json-with-datatable)

Comment: Again as I mentioned in question they able to use this package [ https://pub.dev/packages/json_table ] because their Json response is like `[ {"equipe1":"PSG","equipe2":"DIJON.......} ]`  but my Json response just in `{"DiscountedFee": "80","BookingFee": "50"}`

Comment: above package only work with `ArrayList object` starting and end with `[ ]`

Comment: i have edited my ans did it helped? or are you still stuck